# Fill NA values with another df in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hello I have 2 dataframe

The first

**df1**

```
target Name
SP1.1  Lupus
SP2.2  Canis
SP3.3  Canis
```

and the second where I have NA values in the `Name` columns that I need to fill according to `df1$Name` and `df1$target` matches between the two df
**df2**

```
target Name COLn
SP1.1  <NA>  9
SP2.2  Canis 32
SP3.3  <NA>  78
SP4    Canis 7
```

The expected result would be

**df2**

```
target Name   COLn
SP1.1  Lupus  9
SP2.2  Canis  32
SP3.3  Canis  78
SP4    Canis  7
```

doessomeone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `df1` and `df2` by `target` and select first non-NA value using `coalesce` for `Name` column.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  right_join(df2, by = 'target') %>%
  mutate(Name = coalesce(Name.x, Name.y)) %>%
  select(names(df2))

#  target  Name COLn
#1  SP1.1 Lupus    9
#2  SP2.2 Canis   32
#3  SP3.3 Canis   78
#4    SP4 Canis    7
```

In base R, you can do :

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, all.y = TRUE, by = 'target'), 
          Name = ifelse(is.na(Name.x), Name.y, Name.x))[names(df2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `target` uniquely identifies rows, you can use `dplyr::rows_patch()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  rows_patch(df1, by = "target")

  target  Name COLn
1  SP1.1 Lupus    9
2  SP2.2 Canis   32
3  SP3.3 Canis   78
4    SP4 Canis    7
```